# I'm trying to save the divin image to hosting in javascript but it saves as a blank image

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to save the image of the div as an image to the hosting with javascript bottleCanvas, it puts the image in a div, but when I want to save it as an image file, it saves it as an empty image. How can I solve this problem?

index.php:

```
var bottleCanvas = document.getElementById('kanepe');
var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = dataURL;
anchor.download = 'screenshot.png';
anchor.innerHTML = '<img width="100" height="100" src=' + dataURL + '>download';
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(anchor);
                
                
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'image=' + dataURL,
        success: function(cikti2){
            alert(cikti2);
        }
    })
```

upload.php:

```
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {    

    // get the dataURL
    $dataURL = $_POST["image"];  

    // the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
    // that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
    $data = $parts[1];  

    // Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
    $data = base64_decode($data);  

    // create a temporary unique file name
    $file = "resimler/" . uniqid() . '.png';

    // write the file to the upload directory
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    
    print $success ? $file : "Unable to save this image."; 
}
```

Comment: For starters, you should not send this value without applying proper URL encoding. Use `data: { image: dataURL }`, then jQuery will handle the encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use URLSearchParams, FormData or anything else that requires
to process and read everything into ram first.
I would also not use base64 url encoded string as it increase the bandwidth and
processing time.

just upload the file as is (raw)

```js
const bottleCanvas = document.querySelector('#kanepe')
bottleCanvas.toBlob(async blob => {
    const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    const anchor = document.createElement('a')
    anchor.href = blobURL
    anchor.download = 'screenshot.png'
    anchor.innerHTML = `<img width="100" height="100" src=${blobURL}>download`
    document.querySelector('#output')?.append(anchor)

    // upload to server using -xhr with progress monitor
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload')
    xhr.upload.onprogress = e => {
        // if the upload fails for some reason
        // then you can resume the upload by using blob.slice method
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice
        //
        // const blob = blob.slice(e.loaded)
        console.log(e.loaded / e.total)
    }
    xhr.send(blob)
    xhr.onload = () => {
        alert(xhr.responseText)
    }

    // you could also alternative just use fetch
    const res = await fetch('/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: blob
    })
    const resText = await res.text()
}, 'image/png', 1)
```

Now you also get to know exactly how large the file is before you even start
to processing the file by looking at the content-length. if that's useful for you

but embedding the filename is tricker if you can't use eg: FormData and files
that also sends filename and mime type.

for this reason you can append them to the url params or insert some prefixed `x-` request headers
with this information.

Then try `stream_copy_to_stream`, which directly pumps the content of the input into the file without copying it all into memory first:

```php
    $input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
    $file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
    stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
    fclose($input);
    fclose($file);
```